# Can't get instance of dynamically created ScEditor jQuery plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, sceditor

I'm using [ScEditor](http://www.sceditor.com/) and in normal situations I can get the instance like this, where `sceditor` is the `class` name of the textarea element to attach it to:

```
var instance = $('.sceditor').first().sceditor('instance');
```

However, I have a situation where I need to create an instance of the editor *dynamically*.

Creating it dynamically works fine, however attempting to get the instance doesn't work.

The code executes after a `click` event and on the first click it appears to *create* the instance fine but I cannot get the instance into a variable and work with it; however if I click the link again, I can now work with the instance, presumably because it now exists before I executed the code.

Is there a way I can get the instance in the same call that the instance is created?

Comment: Externally accessible live example please.

Comment: @brunoais nvm....... I figured it out. I was creating the instance within another ajax call because of the way I have to load the emoticons file and hence because of the asynchronous nature of ajax the instance wasn't available yet when I went to get it. I reordered my code and all is well again.